# Verificación de registro en base de datos con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy intentando hacer una verificación en el siguiente método, pero no estaría obteniendo los resultados que espero. Es decir, que se compruebe si existe el **email** ingresado, compare la contraseña enviada con la que se encuentra en la base de datos e inicie la sesión; y en el caso de que no exista, se visualice un mensaje de error sencillo. Aclaro que el inicio de sesión se valida correctamente, lo que no se muestra es el mensaje que indique que el email no existe.

**Código:**

```
public function new_session($email,$password){
        
        $new_connection = new \Models\Connection();
        $connection = $new_connection->run();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(":email",$email);
        $stmt->execute();
            
        while($result = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            if(is_array($result) || is_object($result)){

                if(password_verify($password,$result["password"])){ 
                    $_SESSION["user_session"] = [
                        "user_name" => $result["username"],
                        "user_email" => $result["email"], 
                        "user_password" => $result["password"]
                    ];  
                }
            }else{
                echo "error"; 
            }
        }

        $new_connection = null;
        $connection = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función fetch regresa la fila, si no hay resultados regresa falso y no entra al bucle while por lo que tal vez no es necesario.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php

El flujo debería ser más o menos el siguiente:

```
public function new_session($email,$password){

$new_connection = new \Models\Connection();
$connection = $new_connection->run();
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(":email",$email);
$stmt->execute();

// Esta funcion trae solo la primera fila, si no hay resultados, ya se prueba en la siguiente linea despues de esta.
$result = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Usuario no encontrado";
    return false; // para finalizar en este momento el proceso
}


if(password_verify($password,$result["password"])){
    $_SESSION["user_session"] = [
        "user_name" => $result["username"],
        "user_email" => $result["email"],
        "user_password" => $result["password"]
    ];
    echo "Ingreso existoso";
    return true;
} else {
    echo "Contraseña no válida";
    return false;
}


$new_connection = null;
$connection = null;
```

}

Comment: Gracias Omar por las aclaraciones y lo que señalas con respecto al While.